# How can I write path for executable in px-echo module in pypx library in python on wimdows 10

Tags: python

I am working on pypx library for pacs. Can anyone please suggest what is the path we have to mention here. What is this path referring to?

```
pacs_settings = {
  'executable': '/usr/local/bin/echoscu',
  'aec': 'ORTHANC',
  'aet': 'CHIPS',
  'server_ip': '127.0.0.1',
  'server_port': '4242',
}
```

what is the path referred here for executable,what is it exactly referring to??

Please guide in this part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is referring to `echoscu`:

From the [documentation](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/echoscu.html)

> The  echoscu  application implements a Service Class User (SCU) for the Verification SOP Class. It sends a DICOM C-ECHO message  to  a  Service Class  Provider  (SCP) and waits for a response. The application can be used to verify basic DICOM connectivity.

Assuming you are running Linux, then you should have this installed. You can type `which echoscu` to get the path to it, if it's not in `/usr/local/bin/` (I don't know if different distro's put stuff elsewhere)

Comment: Sorry but I am working on windows..so please suggest solution considering it..Please also suggest how to install echosku. I have installed pypx,so do we need to install echosku too.if yes please elaborate how

Comment: Sorry, I've not got a clue. It looks to be Linux only, as far as I can see.

Comment: >>> import pypx
>>> pacs_settings = {
...   'executable': 'C:/Python35/pypx-0.01/bin/px-echo',
...   'aec': 'ORTHANC',
...   'aet': 'CHIPS',
...   'server_ip': '127.0.0.1',
...   'server_port': '4242',
... }
>>> output = pypx.echo(pacs_settings)
>>> print(output)

Comment: I am getting the following error whille running the above                         
 {'command': 'C:/Python35/pypx-0.01/bin/px-echo --timeout 5  -aec ORTHANC -aet CHIPS 127.0.0.1 4242', 'status': 'error', 'data': 'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n'}  The path here I have mentioned is that of px-echo file located inside bin.